# building thin devices, how to get started?

Tags: pcb-design, pcb-fabrication, pcb-assembly

I want to build thin devices, just as thin as those ipod touches, how do I get started?
What courses, what machines, what books?

Comment: Do you currently have any experience making anything electronic? Knowing this would help us better advise you.

Comment: Question is too vague and should be closed.

Comment: Start by building thick devices which work and learn to make them thinner.

Comment: "learn to make them thinner." - I don't have any shrinkrays... :P

Comment: I originally thought this was a simple question, but it now seems the OP is asking what color to paint the bathroom of the house he wants to build himself but has no idea how houses are constructed.

Answer (score 6):

There is nothing magic about thin devices.  They require no special electronics knowledge.  It's mostly a mechanical issue and choosing parts with minimum height off the board.  It can mean designing for part value you know will come in smaller packages.  A 1 mF 10 V cap is going to take some bulk, for example.  But, mostly it's about the grunt work to find versions of parts with minimum height.  The biggest issue is usually connectors.  Connectors optimized for small size sometimes come in versions that are in the plane of the board in stead of sitting on top of it.

Comment: So, where do I find those wifi, batteries, voltage transformers, microphones, etc. with minimal height?

Comment: @user1095332 - try your local Radio Shack. But I warn you, surface mount components generally aren't for the casual hobbyist, as soldering them is hard work unless you have a reflow station.

Comment: @user: No, don't waste your time at Radio Shack.  They barely sell electronic components and what they do sell is aimed at hobbyists.  Look around on the web sites of real distributors, like Mouser, DigiKey, Neward/Farnell, etc.  Also, surface mount parts are easier to solder than thru hole, except for the very small ones.  You seem to be interested in height off the board, not board area, so you can use comfortable resistors like 0805 size.  There will be other parts taller than those, so that's no limiting factor.

Comment: Thanks. Now, Can I find some books on how to build my own device with the different parts I will order? For example, a small wifi microphone that can be plugged to 240V AC?

Comment: Uh... a small wifi microphone?  That can be plugged into 240VAC?  There's just so many things wrong with that.

Comment: Apple's magic is having enough money to have vendors make thinner parts.

Comment: @AngryEE: No, there's nothing wrong with that. You are just too angry ;) Lets start with the thin wifi microphone part, forget about the 24VAC. How to get started?

Comment: @user1095332 - You're kind of asking "how do I build a space-shuttle?", when you have never even built a model rocket before. Start with a microphone and preamp, learn how to add the required hardware and software to digitize the audio, and when you get that working, **then** *maybe* you can look into WiFi. After that, you will have enough general knowledge to consider packing constraints.

Comment: @FakeName +1 for "**then** *maybe*".  I'll put this to a good use.

Comment: Not to mention that WiFi in itself is a huge and complex subject, requiring knowledge of RF electronics, EMI, software development, 802.11 protocols, the IP stack, etc, etc...

Comment: @NickAlexeev - Hah. I like playing with the markup. I generally try to represent how I would enunciate and weight the words in real speech as text.

Comment: Tell you what user, you show me ANY wifi microphone and I'll tell you how to make a thinner one.